# How to add a dropdown <option> in a rails form?

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu, scaffolding, selectlist

I had created a scaffold-

```
rails g scaffold shipment name:string description:text from:string to:string date:string pay:string
```

I want the `form:string` to be a drop down (with Kolkata/Delhi/Mumbai as options) and not a text field. How can I do this?

I had searched the web but everything was too upper level. I am new to Rails and am trying to learn this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the select helper in your `app\views\shipments\_form.html.erb` file

```
<%= form_for(@shipment) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :from %><br>
    <%= f.select :from, [ 'Kolkata','Delhi','Mumbai' ], :prompt => 'Select One' %>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: okay thanks but can you please tell me where to put this....sorry for this weird question but as i said above am new to all this

Comment: thanks @mezbah it worked i just this line in my form.html.erb file and it worked like magic thanks once again